# I have been person X?

Tags: tenses, present-tense, perfect-aspect

When saying goodbye and thank you after hosting something, it is common to say something like "I have been your host" or "I, person X, have been your host" BUT, would it also be correct to simply say "I have been person X" Even though one does in fact continue to be person X after the event has ended?

I have seen examples of this  (Stephen Fry to be more precise), but is it a correct use of grammar?

The wording was: "You have been watching QI, I have been Stephen Fry. Thank you and good night!"

Comment: The  wording was: "You have been watching QI, I have been Stephen Fry. Thank you and good night!"

Comment: The grammar is fine, but the logic is a little questionable. But this is apparently a TV personality ["sign-off catch-phrase"](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SigningOffCatchPhrase) and those don't necessarily sound like something a regular person would ever say. For example, Walter Winchell's sign-off apparently included the phrase *with lotions of love* (b/c product placement) which sounds ridiculous. Also, note that while it's common for people who are *paid* hosts of some sort to use the *I have been your* [host/pilot/chef] line, it would be very strange in a personal situation.

Answer (score 3):

It helps to know that Stephen Fry is well known as a comedian. This is his little joke. When he uses the **present perfect** to say

> You **have been** watching *QI*

he means that the quiz program that you were just viewing is over and that you are no longer watching because of that fact.  He then says

> I have been Stephen Fry

which was, of course, true during the program but is a ridiculous parallel since obviously he still is Stephen Fry and doesn't stop being Stephen Fry when you're no longer watching him. He could have used the **enduring present**:

> I **am** Stephen Fry

or the **simple past** for a completed role:

> I, Stephen Fry, **was** your presenter.

But neither of those include the kind of word play that's a part of his humor. (For an example of his playing with language, go [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hNoS2BU6bbQ).)

Answer (score 0):

It's humour. It's funny because, in the context, the present perfect suggests that the action is over and completed.

It's "You have been watching" (present perfect continuous) instead of "you are watching" because of the implication that the show is now over. It's "You have been watching" instead of "You were watching" because he's implying the past event still has a bearing on the present, and in this case, because the show has only just finished, he's correct. Recency being something often signified by the present perfect in English.

By saying "I have been Stephen Fry" he therefore seems to suggest that he has recently ceased to be Stephen Fry now that the show has come to an end. It's particularly fitting because while his name is "Stephen Fry", he is, nonetheless, a celebrity personality who takes on a certain persona for the purposes of entertainment.

It's just him being witty. You're quite correct that normally it would be correct to say this only if you've recently ceased performing a role like being a host. He's subtlely suggesting to the audience that in the mind of the viewer "Stephen Fry" is just a role or persona, which of course is true.